# RegEx match for website

Tags: regex, powershell-3.0

I currently have the following script:

```
$ie = New-Object -comObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate('http://www.hotnewhiphop.com/top100')
$null = $ie.Document.body.innerhtml -match '<em\sclass="chartItem-bubble-rank">1</em>(.|\n)*<a\stitle="(.*)"\sclass="chartItem';$hotnewhiphop1song = $matches[2];$hotnewhiphoptop100 += $hotnewhiphop1song
$null = $ie.Document.body.innerhtml -match '<em\sclass="chartItem-bubble-rank">2</em>(.|\n)*<a\stitle="(.*)"\sclass="chartItem';$hotnewhiphop2song = $matches[2];$hotnewhiphoptop100 += $hotnewhiphop2song
$null = $ie.Document.body.innerhtml -match '<em\sclass="chartItem-bubble-rank">3</em>(.|\n)*<a\stitle="(.*)"\sclass="chartItem';$hotnewhiphop3song = $matches[2];$hotnewhiphoptop100 += $hotnewhiphop3song
$null = $ie.Document.body.innerhtml -match '<em\sclass="chartItem-bubble-rank">4</em>(.|\n)*<a\stitle="(.*)"\sclass="chartItem';$hotnewhiphop4song = $matches[2];$hotnewhiphoptop100 += $hotnewhiphop4song
```

Above is only 4 sections of the script, song number 1-4 of the website. There are 20 songs initially on the site, but 100 songs all up. Firstly, the RegEx I am using doesn't match the exact song, it's finding the last match, I think I need to somehow make this non-greedy, but could be wrong.

The song numbers are listed with this value **chartItem-bubble-rank**

The other thing is, when navigating to the site itself, initially there is only 20 songs, however as we scroll down with the mouse more songs start to appear, there's 100 songs in total that I want to capture all to the variable  **$hotnewhiphoptop100**

Comment: Try to use lazy matching and character classes: `[\s\S]*?` instead of `(.|\n)*` and `[^"]*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: Nice one, this worked, thanks

Comment: Actually, can you please explain this for me a little bit more?

Comment: Actually, I spoke to soon, the return I get is Eminem - Sway In The Morning Freestyle" class="chartItem-cover-anchor" href="/eminem-sway-in-the-morning-freestyle-new-song      Is there a slight adjustment you can give me?

Comment: You might try [`<em\s+class="chartItem-bubble-rank">\d+</em>[\s\S]*?<a\s[^>]*title="([^>"]*)"\sclass="chartItem`](https://regex101.com/r/vX4oR2/1). It is reall hard to use regex to extract data from HTML. You'd better do it with HTML parser.